# Regex to exclude character

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hi I want to check in an ASP TextBox that user does not enter the following characters:

```
&'"<>
```

I have given a CustomValidator like

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvtxtName" runat="server" OnServerValidate="SpecialCharactersFilter" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Special characters not allowed" />
```

And c# code

```
protected void SpecialCharactersFilter(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsValid = !Regex.IsMatch(e.Value, @"");
    }
```

But I'm stuck at writing the regex.

Comment: Any attempts to write one, so far?

Comment: Look up character classes, this might help...

Comment: why not use regularexpressionvalidator : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 e.IsValid = Regex.IsMatch(e.Value, "^[^&'\"<>]+$");
```

`^` marks the beginning of the string

`[^]` means that any char inside the square brackets is not allowed

`+` means one time or more (meaning that your input must be at least 1 character long to pass the IsMatch test)

`$` marks the end of the string

Comment: gotta escape the " ... ""

Comment: for getting .net regex this tool is good ... http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx ... if you get a match you get the proper verbatim string in the results you can just copy / paste

Comment: you could have left the @ and just write "" instead of "

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger" it has the same result, right?

Comment: Can i use this regex in RegularExpressionValidator?

Comment: Yes... i said you could have... if you have to use more \ ... like '\s' '\w' or something this becomes less readable...

Comment: how to escape the " inside the bracket

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void SpecialCharactersFilter(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    e.IsValid = !Regex.IsMatch(e.Value, @"[&'""<>]+");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you use a `CustomValidator` instead of a `RegularExpressionValidator` i will show you a non-regex solution:

```
e.IsValid = !e.Value.Intersect("&'\"<>").Any();
```

You need to add `using System.Linq` for the   extension methods.

Comment: You really are at daggers drawn with regex =)

Comment: @florian: You've got me there :)

Comment: Or even a non-linq solution: `e.IsValid = (str.IndexOfAny("&'\"<>".ToCharArray()) == -1)`

Comment: I'm really interested in why? readablility or just a really strong form of antipathy?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: Both, i needed regex  too rarely, so i always have to think about it too long. Since i don't want that always if i look at my old code, i prefer non-regex solutions whenever  poossible. As a side effect non-regex approaches are often more efficient (although also negligible in most cases).

Comment: @TimSchmelter How to give the Validationexpression in RegularExpressionValidator if i want to use it?

Comment: @Niar: you haven't used it, so i've showed you a non-regex approach. If you want to use a `RegularExpressionValidator` use a regular-expression. You can't use string methods or LINQ with a `RegularExpressionValidator`  but you can use any code with your `CustomValidator`.